# Can execute code only after closing a form?

Tags: c#

I need to use frm.show for some reasons and no frm.showdialog. But i need to execute my code after closing my form.

Here is my example

```
private void Example1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();

        MessageBox.Show("EXECUTE CODE");
    }

    private void Example2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();

        MessageBox.Show("EXECUTE CODE");
    }
```

In first example my code runs ok. But in second one i get Message imidiatelly when i'm opening the form. I need to make it work like first one.Is there any other way to make it work like example 1?

Comment: An an event handler to the close event and execute the code there.

Comment: You can add an event handler for the Form1.Closing event and do you work when the engine calls your event handler.

Comment: Or creating a public event for this and executing when my form is closing?

Comment: @DimChris Why try to invent the wheel?  The closing event was made for exactly this.

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Yes, [Form.Closed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) event is all what you need

Comment: To execute code from anther form keep the 2nd form running and just make invisible so you can call the form multiple times using the same instance.